# I Can't edit style.min.css on bootstrap

Tags: header, edit

on www.PlummerWigger.com, there are many items that I just can't seem to access. There are two .css - style.css and style.min.css

The first is to remove the space the head is floating in (space on top and bottom) 
The second is to access the #header .entry-header (or the text:New York State...")

Can't seem to get ahold of them.

bam

Answer (score 0):

`style.min.css` means that it is minified. In simple words, its compressed by removing extra space to decrease file size. It is not a good practice to edit it.

Every wordpress theme comes with field to enter your own CSS content, better use it. If not then create another css file, put the code and link it.

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying with it, but I still can't seem to do either of the above (plus many other tests).

Comment: find/replace, copy directly from web, chopped 500 line peices out of it to isolate it...

Comment: @user3381755 try adding `!important` tag to css you want to change in case you are overriding the css in style.min.css

Comment: Each time I tried one thing, I tried that right after.

Comment: Thanks - the !important worked - I was putting it in the wrong place. :(

Comment: If you really want to edit minified css edit and then use https://cssminifier.com/ or something to minifier / compressor